# Data is not showing

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, bootstrap-table

I am trying to display data from my database using bootstrap table, php and javascript. I have this code:

index.html

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
       <table  id="table"
                    data-show-columns="true"
                    data-height="500">
       </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

javascript

```
var $table = $('#table');
     $table.bootstrapTable({
        url: 'list-farmers.php',
        search: true,
        pagination: true,
        buttonsClass: 'primary',
        showFooter: true,
        minimumCountColumns: 2,
        columns: [{
            field: 'landID',
            title: 'ID',
            sortable: true,
        },{
            field: 'location',
            title: 'Location',
            sortable: true,
        },{
            field: 'surf_area',
            title: 'Surface Area',
            sortable: true,

        },{
            field: 'surf_unit',
            title: 'Unit',
            sortable: true,

        },{
            field: 'ownership',
            title: 'Ownership',
            sortable: true,

        },{
            field: 'soiltype',
            title: 'Soil Type',
            sortable: true,                
        }, ],

     });
```

php

```
include 'dbconnect.php';

$sqltran = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM land where farmerID = 8")or die(mysqli_error($con));
$arrVal = array();

$i=1;
while ($rowList = mysqli_fetch_array($sqltran)) {

        $name = array(
            'num' => $i,
            'landID'=>$rowList['landID'],
            'location'=> $rowList['location'],
            'surf_area'=> $rowList['surf_area'],
            'surf_unit'=> $rowList['surf_unit'],
            'ownership'=> $rowList['ownership'],
            'soiltype'=> $rowList['soiltype']
          );    


          array_push($arrVal, $name); 
  $i++;     
}
   echo  json_encode($arrVal); 

mysqli_close($con);
```

There must be something wrong with the codes because when I run it, the table and the design is there, but there is no data.

[image: This is the result of the code]

This is the data in the database that should match.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure there's any matching data in the database?

Comment: yes, there is one match. Also I tried to select all data from land table and it still doesn't display.

Comment: Try using the dev tools on your browser to see if list-farmers.php is correctly returning a MIME_TYPE of application/json and not application/html

Comment: I do not see any error handling on the server side. You actually do not have any idea if anything goes wrong there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If you are certain there's no error in your **db-connect.php** file.
  Your list-farmers.php looks good, but i suspect it's returning an html page.

Add this to your list-farmers.php, right after your opening  tag

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

YES! I found out the reason,

1. As you all have said, the MIME_TYPE is application/html. So I put 
   header('Content-Type: application/json');
2. And my dbconnect.php was like this:

   ```
   $user = 'root';
   $pass = '';
   $db = 'farmingportal';
   $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', $user, $pass, $db);
   if($con){
       echo 'success!';
   }else {
       echo 'not successful';
   }
   ```

so I just erased the if statement..